# redis-server takes a long time to load in memory the dataset at boot

Tags: linux, redis

My Linux distribution uses the `redis` database.
At boot the `redis-server` needs about 80 seconds to load the dataset. The following is a log that shows what I have written:

```
redis-server[249]: 249:M 17 Oct 2022 16:29:55.173 * DB loaded from append only file: 79.442 seconds
```

If a Python program tries querying the database before the `redis-server` finishes the loading in memory operation, it is raised the Exception: `redis.exceptions.BusyLoadingError`.
The Exception message error is: `Redis is loading the dataset in memory` and is compliant with the context that I have described.

Because I'm using the default configuration of `redis-server` in this moment I don't know exactly what is the type of persistence used by `redis-server`.
The file `redis.conf` is very long so, here, I report settings that I think are most important:

```
...
################################ SNAPSHOTTING  ################################
#
# Save the DB on disk:
#
#   save <seconds> <changes>
#
#   Will save the DB if both the given number of seconds and the given
#   number of write operations against the DB occurred.
# OE: tune for a small embedded system with a limited # of keys.
save 120 1
save 60 100
save 30 1000

############################## APPEND ONLY MODE ###############################
# OE: changed default to enable this
appendonly yes

# The name of the append only file (default: "appendonly.aof")
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
...
```

These settings seem indicate that the database is using the persistence type: `Append Only File` (`AOF`).
I think these configuration cause a so long loading time.

Is it possible to use settings that avoid a too long loading time at boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is a ***disk-backed all-in-memory database***, so either you diminish your database size for initial load, or you give redis faster disks; that's all the alternatives you have. This isn't related whether your configuration uses aof or not: on the initial load redis will have to read all the data regardless of the number of files it's in.

Comment: Thank you very much.